# C++ Struct in 'n' Dimensions

Tags: c++, struct

I am working on a series of problems in higher dimensionality, and was hoping someone could offer me some broad advice:

Consider a struct representing a point in two (2) dimensions:

```
struct p2 {
    double x, y;
    p2(double x, double y) : x(x),y(y){}
};
```

This point can be easily extended to three (3) dimensions:

```
struct p3 : p2 {
    double z;
    p3(double x, double y, double z) : p2(x,y),z(z){}
};
```

But how do you handle the case for 'n' dimensions, where the n could be 4, 5, 6, or anything higher for that matter, and only known at runtime. In other words, the user might supply 2D data, or 3D or 4D etc...

I am open to other solutions other than C++, however, assume this a numerically intense problem, and therefore functional and/or scripting languages should probably be avoided.

Comment: Use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: or, for compile-time metaprogramming, [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

Comment: `std::valarray` may also be of interest.

Comment: Yes, vector or `std::array` if the dimension is a compile time constant and not huge.

Comment: @BaummitAugen for me it is not a compile time constant, in my case it will be a runtime constant, ie, dependent on what the user wants to do.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes I thought this might be the best way, I am just trying to see what other methods there are. Thanks.

Comment: @NicholasHamilton Then `std::vector` is the correct way. Or maybe [`boost.small_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/container/small_vector.html) if the number of dimensions is usually kind of small and the allocation overhead matters.

Comment: If you thought about the vector and it exactly matches your problem, why the heck would you go try to find a different more complicated way to "dynamically create 'n' fields of the same type" (a.k.a. *a vector/array*)

Comment: Because it doesn't 'exactly' match the problem. With structs and member variables, you can create getter and setters. You can write functions that depend on those named variables, you can compare two structs of 'type' etc.... With a vector, all you really know is that is a container of type, containing 'n' number of items, its far less formal.

Comment: Oh, but the vector can underly your custom class as a data holder, and you write all the getters you want around it, like a subscript operator... oh wait ;-).

Comment: And you'll have a hard time coming up with named variables at runtime.

Comment: @PeterSchneider Yes I am aware of that, hence the question.

Comment: 'far less formal'? Srsly? A vector of size 'n' and type 'T' is an element of T^n with some additional functionality (you can use an array if you don't want that). Ok, I'll be explicit because as it seems you don't quite understand what is meant with 'use a vector': Create the `struct MyNDimensionalThingy`; put a vector in there as a (private?) member. Then you write all the getters and setters you want. See? Not 'n'  members of type 'T', but rather a single member with variable size (so dynamic! Much nice! Very runtime! Wow!). Perfect, right? Why not that? *ANY* disadvantages you have in mind?